# Jquery slideDown only after slideUp is completed

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I'm pretty new to jQuery and I've been struggling with the problem for a while and couldn't find the answer. What I am trying to achieve is to slide down the content on click on tab (that works), but then after clicking on another tab I want to slide up the visible content, and only after the animation in finished slide down the new content.
I've tried to set slideDown as a callback to slideUp, but I must have done something wrong, because then the animation didn't work at all.

Here is my code:

```
$('#tabs').on('click', 'a', function(e) {        
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {

        $('#tabs').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.course-level:visible').slideUp();
        $('.course-level[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').slideDown();

      } else {
        $('.course-level:visible').slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
 });
```

And here is working fiddle of what I have been able to get: http://jsfiddle.net/asiek/2UvWX/6/

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the cleanest code by far, but it demonstrates the use of a callback. The function is fired after the slideUp event finishes. Don't use a delay.

http://jsfiddle.net/2UvWX/13/

```
$('#tabs').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var _this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    if( $(_this).hasClass('active') )
    {
        $(_this).removeClass('active');
        $('.course-level:visible').slideUp();
    }
    else
    {
        if( $('.course-level:visible').length > 0 )
        {
            $('#tabs a.active').removeClass('active');

            $('.course-level:visible').slideUp(function() {
                $('.course-level[id=' + $(_this).attr('data-id') + ']').slideDown();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('.course-level[id=' + $(_this).attr('data-id') + ']').slideDown();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ryan, works like a charm! If you don't mind, could you tell me why using a delay is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

I set delay http://jsfiddle.net/2UvWX/12/

```
    $('#tabs').on('click', 'a', function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {

        $('#tabs').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.course-level:visible').slideUp(300);
        $('.course-level[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').delay(300).slideDown();

      } else {
        $('.course-level:visible').slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }

 });
```

Comment: I would if I could - reputation 15 is required and I've just joined stack overflow - I'll come back here when I can up vote. Oh, and I'm a girl, btw ;)